# IF Function in Excel with 2 criteria and 3 outcome

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have data with amounts in column A and B. In column C I need a formula that IF the value in column A is greater than zero and the value in column B is equal to zero the outcome will be "A" IF the data in Column A is equal to zero and Column B is greater than zero the outcome should be "B" and IF both Column "A" and "B" is greater than 0 the outcome should be "False"

I don't know if this is even possible with IF function. Thanks,

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I mean for the outcome should be literally "A" or "B" not the value in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use multiple IF statements.

Either

```
=IF(A1>0, IF(B1=0, "A", "False"), IF(A1=0, IF(B1>0, "B", "False")))
```

Or

```
=IF(AND(A1>0, B1=0), "A", IF(AND(A1=0, B1>0), "B", "False"))
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the changes from A1->"A" and B1->"B". Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

You should nest it - forgive me if the syntax is slightly off, but-

=IF(AND(A>0,B=0), A, IF(AND(A=0,B>0), B, "False"))